# source ~/.profile paths are not being followed by OSX

Tags: macos, openssl, .profile

I am having issues where the paths I created in `source ~/.profile` are not being used at all. I confirmed the paths I created by executing `echo $PATH` --- all of my custom-made paths in .profile show up.

Separately, I checked for `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` and both do not exist (are completely empty when I sudo pico). I also confirmed I'm in the .zsh shell if that matters.

So as an example, I have an openssl 3.0 installation in one of the defined paths in /.profile. However, when I `which openssl` it is returning `usr/bin/openssl` which is not the path in my .profile.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS Catalina (10.15), the default shell on macOS is no more **bash** but **zsh**. Your config files are for **bash**, in **zsh** it'**.zprofile**.
Could you check what shell do you use with this command ?
`echo $SHELL`

You can use this command to change your shell `chsh -s /bin/bash` or in Terminal go to Preferences to modify the configuration and
add `export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1` in **.profile**.
Close your Terminal's window and open a new one to validate the change.

If you want use **.profile** for your config, you can add `[[ -e ~/.profile ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'` in your **.zprofile** to load your config.

Comment: thx, I had mentioned that "I also confirmed I'm in the .zsh shell if that matters".